# Website crawling with python and beautiful soup is not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to fetch each NSN and description next to it from this site http://www.iso-parts.com/Index/1.

The code I attempted is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
import pyrebase


from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

NSNurl = 'http://www.iso-parts.com/Index/1'
uClient = requests.get(NSNurl, verify=False)
page_html = uClient.content

# close client
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
container = page_soup.find_all("td", {"class": "tdD"})

for container1 in container:
        NSN = container1.find("td", {"class": "tdD"})
        print(NSN)
```

Instead of getting a list of NSNs, such as `1005-00-130-5515`, all I get is `None`. How can I fetch all the NSNs in the site?

Comment: any comment why this was downvoted?

Comment: Try printing `container1` -- or perhaps `pprint(container1.__dict__)` (after `from pprint import pprint`) to print all the attributes and their values. I often use this is a quick and dirty debug tool to test my assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you're getting all of the `td` and then looking for a `td` inside each of them, one by one.

```
container = page_soup.find_all("td", {"class": "tdD"})

for container1 in container:
        #container1 is a <td></td>
        NSN = container1.find("td", {"class": "tdD"}) #here
        print(NSN)
```

Instead, you need to grab the text value of the anchor inside of `container1`

Also, there are actually two `<td>` with class `tdD`, in each row. The value of the number, and the text description. So you should skip over the ones that don't have an anchor nested in them.

```
for container1 in container:    #container1 is <td> element
     nsn = container1.find('a') #get the anchor from the <td>
     if nsn is not None:        #if an anchor is found
         print(nsn.contents[0]) #print it
     else:
         print(container1.text) #the description
```

Comment: all i get back is "none"

Comment: that's because i pasted the part of your code that contains the flaw, to draw your attention to it

Comment: thank you! it worked, so to get description it will be container1.text

Comment: the description is in container1s that don't have an anchor child. So you could do 
if nsn is not None:
 #this is the number value
else:
 #this is the description

Comment: oh I mean how can the description next to the numbers be retrieved since its just tagged <td class="tdD">SPOOL AND SLEEVE ASSEMBLY</td>. I've tried container1.text and many other variations but no luck

Comment: I've updated the answer, since including code isn't possible in comments

Comment: great. thats what I was looking for. I thought I had tried that before but oh well. Thanks